# ошибка var_dump

Tags: php, yii2, xampp

пишу проект на yii2. при использовании var_dump для отладки показывает ошибку такого типа

> An Error occurred while handling another error:
>   yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amicum\controllers\AlgorithmAmicumController.php on
>   line 30.

Собственно на 30 строчке вызов var_dump. и каждый раз в новом месте прекращается вызов var_dump. но иногда такая ошибка возникает и при переборе foreach.
сервер запущен через xampp. на сервере линуксе все нормально работает.
вопрос по большей части в том, чтобы подобняа ошибка не возникала на серваке в дальнейшем. ну и как исправить. возможно надо что то прописать в настройках xampp?

Comment: Доброе утро. "Headers already sent" настолько избитая тема, что инет ломится от решений.

Comment: @slo_nik но вот что то ничего из того, что там описано не срабатывает